# React Native render error while trying to render multiple components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, runtime-error

I want to render multiple copies of the same custom component that I built after a user presses the 'Add' button. My code is as follows:

```
import "react-native-get-random-values";
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Text, TouchableHighlight, Button } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import Lift from './Lift'

export default function Lifts() {
  // const [cards, setCards] = useState([{ id: uuidv4() }])
  // const onPress = () => setCards([...cards, [{ id: uuidv4() }]])
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([uuidv4()])
  const onPress = () => setCards([...cards, uuidv4()])

  const liftCards = cards.map((id) => {
    return (
      <View key={id}>
        <Lift />
      </View>
    )
  })

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress} underlayColor={'#DDDDDD'} style={styles.touchable}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Text>
            Add Lift
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      {/* <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', top: 100 }}>
        {cards}
      </Text> */}
      {
        cards.map((data, id) => {
          return (
            <Text> {id} </Text>
          )
        })
      }
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10,
  },
  touchable: {
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    top: 10
  }
})
```

in the above snippet  is the custom component that I want to display on screen. The issue I run into is that after I click 'Add Lift' a couple of times, I get an error that says "undefined is not a function." The error I get:

```
ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function

This error is located at:
    in Lifts (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

I'm fairly confident that the issue lies within my use of the `uuidv4()` functionality because when I use the exact same code but print the length of the `cards` array with just 1, 2, 3... as id numbers instead of `uuidv4()`, it outputs the right number with the correct increment on every press as well. I expect the same result while using `uuidv4()` and the number of custom `<Lift />` cards to match the length of `cards`

EDIT: I have provided some screenshots for the error as seen from my mobile device
[Error on mobile device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afHum.jpg) [Error on mobile device continued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZKpR.jpg)

Comment: This code, copy/pasted into a running [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/react-native-render-error-while-trying-to-render-multiple-components) runs and renders without issue. Is this an issue in the `liftCards` array that  isn't rendered? Can you [edit] to include all relevant code and any more details regarding the error/issue?

Comment: @Drew, I just ran the Expo snack link you posted and it works all right. That's very peculiar because it does not behave the same way when I run it on my mobile. When I click "Add cards" a couple of times, the error pasted in the question is what is thrown at me.

Comment: Can you fork that snack and add more of the actual code you are using that we could then inspect?

Comment: @Drew, I was not able to figure out how to fork the snack. But I did edit the [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@anisr/react-native-render-error-while-trying-to-render-multiple-components) and my entire code is on there now. The only issue is, its not able to resolve the react-navigation library. Maybe you'll have more luck

Comment: You should only need to save the snack and it should create a new copy of it for you. Using `"@react-navigation/native": "6.1.6",` seems to have worked and the snack appears to run without issue. Can you clarify again what the issue is/was?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion regarding the navigation. This is frustrating because as you have said, the code is running as expected on snack. But when I run that exact same code on my mobile device through the expo go app it throws the error I have pasted in the original question. I get the error when I navigate to the `Lifts` screen and click on `Add Lift` a couple of times. I'll edit the main question to illustrate the screenshot with the error.

Comment: @Drew, were the additional images and comment helpful in clarifying the issue a little more?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the images weren't much help. I also think there some issue/discrepancy with the `uuid` library you are using. I've use that library a lot and haven't ever seen this issue though (*I've also not dealt much with React-Native in a few years*). Do you need the polyfill from `import "react-native-get-random-values";`? What happens if you comment that line out? Outside this I'd say to check the respective repos for any reported issues similar to what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to figure out what the issue was, but thanks to the little discussion in the comments, I was given the epiphany that something might not be linking right with the uuid dependencies. So I used a different [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-uuid) package, and it seems to be doing the trick...for now